# Did Cersei intend for her son, King Tommen, to die?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 6 Episode we see that Cersei

> blows up the Sept of Baelor, killing high Septons, quite a handful of Tyrell families and virtually all her known political enemies. Cersei also prevents her son, King Tommen from going to Sept of Baelor for obvious reason. There is a good reason to think that King Tommen is under house arrest, judging from the appearance of Gregor Clegane blocking King Tommen from going out.

Upon hearing the news, King Tommen

> throws himself out of the window and commits suicide.

Is this the outcome Cersei wants? Lest you think the answer is an obvious NO, I would like to offer the following counterpoint:

> Tommen is getting out of control, and being clearly manipulated by High Septons. His presence is a threat to Cersei's freedom and even life, not to mention her political ambition.

And not only that,

> Cersei is seen as not crying when seeing her son body.

So could it be that by doing the above, Cersei forces or at least encourages King Tommen to make that decision?

Comment: Cersei justifies EVERYTHING that she does -either in the books or in the series- with her love for her children. As I don't have the time to search for examples of her stating that, this is only a comment, not a fully flexed answer.

Comment: It could, but, as far as we know, it probably isn't. Part of Cersei's character is that her children are the most important thing in the world to her. Moreover, Tommen is still alive in the books. Unless D&D addressed this directly, I would say that Cersei's potential undisclosed thoughts are a matter of opinion.

Comment: @TorstenLink your comment doesn't seem like answering my question

Comment: She does everything for her children... that contradicts her wanting her son to commit suicide

Comment: He is alive in the books, but Cersei didnt blow up the Sept of Baelor either (yet), unless my memory has slipped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would be a pretty radical departure from her character in both the books and the show. Cersei is shown to be utterly devoted to her children, and crushed by the deaths of Myrcella and Joffrey (who if anything, was even harder to control than Tommen).

> CERSEI: You may never love the king, but you will love his children.
>
> SANSA: I love His Grace with all my heart.
>
> CERSEI: That's so very touching to hear. Permit me to share some
>   womanly wisdom with you on this very special day. The more people you
>   love, the weaker you are. You'll do things for them that you know you
>   shouldn't do. You'll act the fool to make them happy, to keep them
>   safe. Love no one but your children. On that front, a mother has no
>   choice. (Season Two, "A Man Without Honor")

You're correct that Cersei does not mourn Tommen's death, but in the Season Seven premiere it's revealed she's harboring resentment against Tommen for his suicide and she does indeed love him.

> JAIME: We never talked about Tommen.
>
> CERSEI: There's nothing to say.
>
> JAIME: Our baby boy killed himself.
>
> CERSEI: He betrayed me. He betrayed us both. Should we spend our days
>   mourning the dead--mother, father, and all our children?
>
> JAIME: Cersei--
>
> CERSEI: I loved them. I did. But they're ashes now and we're still
>   flesh and blood. We're the last Lannisters, the last ones who count.

I guess she could be lying here, but if Cersei wanted Tommen dead, why wouldn't she have just allowed him to go to the Sept? Why wouldn't the writers have fully conveyed such a dark and meaningful character moment? The simpler explanation by far is that Cersei wanted Tommen alive, and than suffered a psychotic break/survivor's guilt once he was dead.